# Is Facebook iOS app built in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I came across an article that gave me the impression that Facebook's iOS app is built in React Native.

Does anyone know if this true?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One of my friend who was interviewed at FB 5 months ago was told that more than 80% of the application is still native.

I realized what is the point of moving over to React Native from Native for big companies? rather stay native and give the best user experience!

Comment: Reminds me of the time I got into a heated argument with a CTO during an job interview 4 years ago. The CTO thought the path to go was Xamarin, whereas I thought the path to go was native. I pointed out many examples why Xamarin was a bad idea and for a moment the other directors started asking me more about the pros/cons. The CTO quickly ended the interview...LOL.

Comment: React Native/ Flutter this will die soon. Every middleware library which has been emerged before is dead now. Only native will stay. So stay away from non native middleware library.

Comment: @Learner The transition from any to another app takes a lot of money and time even for facebook.
Neither React Native nor Flutter will die at least as long as we're alive.
They're just making a lot of progress.
Every middleware library which has been emerged hasn't been good.

But React is amazing.
It will never die, as long as nothing better comes, and native specially Android Native sucks, and is no better.

Plus why would you use it when you can bridge everything on javascript?
It's like not using typescript, it's just a better javascript. React native is a better native :).

Comment: @stevemoretz you can never get all the native api in middleware. Middleware will always behind from the latest native api, latest bug fixes, latest tools.
For optimization purposes(memory,processing,threading), you must need native api, instrumentation, debugging tools. you can never get all those in middleware. For making a fast launching, fast responsive, low power consuming app you must need the help of instrumentation with the versatile native api. However, I also don’t like android api quality and documentation but they are improving.

Comment: @Learner what you are saying is all true, but middlewares are also making huge improvements.You can never always be up to date, with. latest native api, is true but your really don't need too, middlewares were horribly weak before, but now memory management, processing , threading and everything else is becoming better and better, latest animation library for react native, runs on 60 fps even for complex animations, the build system expo team is building right now, is going to be also a huge hit, also don't forget Google is behind flutter and facebook and microsoft are working on react native

Answer (score 15):

Facebook claims:

**"Using React Native in the Facebook app".**

It means that they have used React Native partially in app. But the point is to what extent they have used React native, no one knows.

So, it seems like most of the core is build in native but they have started implementing new modules in React Native.

Comment: I can see it with looking at it.

Answer (score 3):

> It's also easy to build part of your app in React Native, and part of
>   your app using native code directly - that's how the Facebook app
>   works.

This is the [official words](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) from Facebook. it means Facebook did not use completely react native. it is partially using react native in their apps.

Answer (score 1):

https://reactnative.dev/showcase

Yes it is true. You can see the list of apps in this section.

Comment: I don't think the whole app is built with react native. The most important part is probably still native.

Comment: Doesn't matter what is native, react native is nothing but native over a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main tabs, **Facebook Marketplace**, is built with React Native.
https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/08/07/react-native-performance-in-marketplace

Comment: This is a broken link now.